# How to get position of carriage from textArea during input text

Tags: html, reactjs

How to get position of carriage (x and y coordinates) from `textarea` during input text.

Comment: does this help you - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getboundingclientrect.asp#:~:text=The%20getBoundingClientRect()%20method%20returns,%2C%20y%2C%20width%2C%20height.

Comment: Yea, it doesn't help me. It shows the same coordinates in textarea.

Comment: I managed with my problem using this library: https://codesandbox.io/s/h6rw4?file=/src/App.tsx:352-358

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly, you can do it with JQuery:

```
position = $('#textArea').prop("selectionStart");
```

Comment: How to do it in reactJS?

Comment: I try to it: console.log('selectionStart', document.getElementById("textarea").selectionStart), but i always see undefined.

Comment: document.getElementById("textarea").selectionStart; is giving me the correct output,
I didn't fully understand your question, what do you mean by carriage ?

Comment: It is mean 'caret'